# ZPL Loop function

Tags: sql, qr-code, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm looking for any idea can help to setup a ZPL label using a loop function to gather the information from SQL Table and print them on a label

I have a Table in SQL DB has those fields
Product
QTY
ORDER_NR

for example:

I have the order 111022 has 3 items lines

- 50023
- 50037
- 50099

And I want to create a label using the ZPL code with a loop functions so the all items ordered will be printed on that label

Order : 111022

- Item : 50023 - QTY = 7
- Item : 50037 - QTY = 5
- Item : 50099 - QTY = 2

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ZPL` is only a markup language, unfortunately there are no loops and also no database functions!

To achieve what you want, you have to write some sort of software in a programming language of your choice.
This software will then read the data from the database using `SQL` and depending on the gathered records it can then write `ZPL` code to print them on the label.